# Use of MapActivity with Android API 8

Tags: android-maps

I'm fairly new to Android development. I'm trying to understand how to implement Maps on a Froyo device. Unfortunately the books I'm using all reference the use of MapActivity in all their examples and the associated classes/methods (e.g., MapView). So here are my questions:

1) It is my understanding that MapActivity (and associated classes) are not available prior to Honeycomb (even with the support library). Is this correct?

2) If they aren't available then generally speaking how do you work around this issue? (e.g., is there a alternative support library available which allows you to use MapViews on a Froyo device?

3) I'm struggling with how best to learn Map APIs given that I only have a Froyo device? Ordinarily my approach would be to use the emulator to first learn the Map API on a Honeycomb+ device and then having done that I'd figure out how to "translate" that so that it works on a Froyo device.

Unfortunately using the emulator with v2 Map API is not possible (as far as I know) and I'm not in a position to upgrade my phone to a Android device running Honeycomb+. Then you add the complexity of the recent "shift" by Google from v1 to v2 Map API (which my books don't even reference) and now you have what seems to be a very difficult learning curve.

Any general suggestions on how best to learn the Map API given my circumstances (new to MAP API, no Honeycomb+ device, no books that seem to cover this topic, etc)? BTW I tend to prefer resources other than Google as my first read because I find Google documentation to be minimalist and only mildly helpful when you are trying to learn something for the first time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Map V2 in Froyo. There are few changes in order to implement Map V2 in Froyo.

First go through this guide to implement Google Map V2 :[Map V2](http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/02/google-maps-android-api-v2-introduction.html)

Steps of changes in order to implement Map V2 in Froyo:

- use SupportMapFragment instead MapFragment in xml.

- use  mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

instead of

mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: Karn, thank you very much for the reply. I am aware that you can use Google Map v2 in Froyo...and I have since become aware of your suggestions above...use of Support Fragments...however my key question was related to MapActivity but more specifically MapViews and it's various methods (e.g., mapView.setSatellite(), mapView.setTraffic(), mapView.getMaxZoomLevel(), etc., etc.). If I can't use MapViews with  Froyo how do I access methods such as those?

Comment: By the way, when I add the statement "private GoogleMap mMap;" to my code I get the error "GoogleMap type cannot be resolved to a type". So I must be missing some Jars??? Also I get the same message when I use "SupportMapFragment" in the code as per your suggestion above. Thoughts/ideas? Also is the Class that uses this code suppose to extend "Activity" or "FragmentActivity".

Comment: Re: GoogleMap issue I was able to resolve this by adding the dependency to Google Play Services into my project. I can resolve the "SupportMapFragment" IF I extend the Class with FragmentActivity but per my question should I extend with "FragmentActivty" or "Activity" or even "SupportMapFragment". I could use one of the last two items but that causes other compile time issues if I use them. Thoughts?